# How to know the selected firefox save dialog option?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firefox, save

I am using angular 10 (typescript). With **Firefox** I encountered the necessity of knowing what option did I choose in the save dialog.
More details:
Unlike chrome where a blob file is saved directly, Firefox force us to pass through the save dialog with the following available options:

- open with
- Save File
- Cancel
- OK

Here is the firefox dialog I am speeking about
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkXps.png

My behavior (in code), after that user select the option that he wants, depends on the selected option.

Is there any solution that informs me about the selected option.
If this is totally impossible, is there a possibility to force firefox, programatically, to perform the save without passing through the save dialog/popup.
Note disabling the save dialog through firefox setting would NOT be good solution.

Comment: `to force firefox, programatically, to perform the save without passing through the save dialog/popup` so, you want to save files on peoples computers without their permission? That's what it comes down to

Comment: @jaromandaX.
"so, you want to save files on peoples computers without their permission?"
No the user is supposed to click on save button before the save process.
Is it a big deal to know what was the chose of the user ?

Comment: No, it's not a big deal to know what they chose. I don't think you'll be able to know though - but I was commenting on the part where you said you wanted to force the browser to save without using the dialog - I think a user can set that up in the Applications section of Options

Answer (score 0):

I wonder that not many people are interested in this issue !

Isn't this a classic issue ?

I have imagined that it interests lots of applications/websites to make some handling after user file save action, for example :

1 - disabling save button until the user makes some new changes.

2 - allow the user to leave with/without asking about unsaved changes.

...